# How do I get to an offset from a structure? (Hex editor)

Tags: hex, offset

I'm looking at a tiff structure in hex and I found the following: `0x00 0x00 0x02 0x52`. In decimal, that's 594.

I need to get to offset 594 from the beginning of the tiff structure, NOT the beginning of the file. I looked at the Adobe Specification: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf which says that the tiff structure starts at 4D 4D (hex).

I tried right clicking the first '4D' and going to 'Relative Offset' `0x594` in my hex editor but I don't think I'm doing it right.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: "The first 4D" 0x4d != 0x4d4d... Also, 0x594=1428 in decimal... You really need to revise how to calculate in numeral systems with different bases, like the hexadecimal one...

You should get to 0x4d4d (19879 in decimal), and then relative offset 0x252 (which is 954 in decimal). **IF** offset is in bytes, not for example 32bit words, or whatever else...

Comment: ppeterka - I mean 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x52 is 594 in decimal.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x52 is essentially 0x252 (954 in decimal). So I go to offset 0x252. I'll try it - thanks.

Comment: However, looking at the PDF, you are way off. There is nothing about anything starting at 0x4D4D. 0x4D4D in ASCII is `MM`, two capital M letters, meaning the endianness of the given file. Please read the spec and take the time to understand it too.

Comment: Yes there is. The pdf says that the byte header is: 0000 Byte Order 4D4D.  (MM is 4D4D in ASCII). MM appears in the hex editor as 4D4D and in ascii as MM on the right hand side of the editor).

Comment: I got it working in the end. I was right, but instead of searching for 0x594, I just searched for relative offset '594' without the '0x' and it worked. 

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: But that is at address 0 -- meaning that it occupies the first and second bytes of the file. If you highlight the first byte - which is a 4D value, an M letter, then zou are at address 0 of the file. Or in other words: the exact begining. You wrote `I need to get to offset 594 from the beginning of the tiff structure, NOT the beginning of the file`. This seems to be a contradiction. Also `the tiff structure starts at 4D 4D (hex)` actually means that the relevant content begins at the absolute offset of 19879 (decimal), and you need the relative offset starting from that.

Comment: The manual (page 13) states that the first two bytes indicate the endianness of the whole TIFF structure. 'MM' ( 4D 4D in hex) -> big-endian, and 'II' ( 49 49 in hex) indicates little-endian. All numeric values in the rest of the structure are supposed to be in this byte order.